# "EFI variables are not supported on this system"

Tags: uefi

I am attempting to install Arch linux to a new (and very crappy) HP Pavillion 15 Notebook.

This is a UEFI-based machine.  After several swings at it, I have managed to get pretty far.  Legacy mode is disabled in the system setup, and I have EFI-booted to the Arch DVD I burned, and progressed through both the Arch [Beginner's Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide) and the more advanced [Installation Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_Guide) to the point where I am installing grub.

While `chroot`ed, I execute:

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=arch_grub --recheck --debug
```

This emits a ton of output, including:

> EFI variables are not supported on this system

The first time I got to this point, I continued with the installation, not knowing if it was an actual problem.  Turns out it was, as when I rebooted the machine no bootable medium could be found and the machine refused to boot.  I was able at that point to go in to the UEFI setup menu and select an EFI file to boot, and the Arch Linux would boot up.

But I am now going back and reinstalling again, trying to fix the problem above.

How can I get GRUB to install correctly?

Comment: I found a solution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/693111/166985 (`mount -t efivarfs none /sys/firmware/efi/efivars`).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem was simply that the `efivarfs` kernel module was not loaded.

This can be confirmed by:

```
sh-4.2# efivar-tester
UEFI variables are not supported on this machine.
```

If you are `chroot`ed in to your new install, `exit` out, and then enable `efivarfs`:

```
exit
modprobe efivarfs
```

(`efivarfs` used to be `efivars`, so if this returns an error try `modprobe efivars`)

...and then `chroot` back in.  In my case, this means:

`chroot /mnt`

but you should `chroot` the same way you did before.

Once back in, test again:

`efivar-tester`

This will no longer report an error, and you can install grub the same way you did before.

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=arch_grub --recheck --debug
```

Comment: See also http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html

Comment: But what about on a system that doesn't support UEFI? How in the world do I install UEFI-capable GRUB on my USB stick to install Arch on a new UEFI computer if my working computer doesn't support UEFI? There's gotta be a way to do it!

Comment: The efivars module has been replaced by "efivarfs" now (https://wiki.debian.org/UEFI#efibootmgr_and_efivar).

Comment: While `modprobe efivarfs` works, the issue described by the OP persists. maybe this answer needs an update? I'm totally running out of ideas.

Comment: Sadly `modprobe efivars` gives `modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/4.16.3-301.fc28.x86_64` (freshly installed live usb)

Comment: In case you install Arch Linux in VMware (like me), you need to edit `.vmx` file add line `firmware=efi`, boot the installation and then `modprobe efivarfs`, mount drives you need, chroot into it and then `efivar-tester` and if everything is ok continue with `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=GRUB`

Comment: In addition to loading the `efivarfs` module, make sure you've bound the real `/sys` to your chroot `sys`, as this is what the EFI vars are accessed through

Answer (score 44):

I know, that's very old thread, but maybe will help for someone.
Most guides suggest the same solution to mount virtual filesystems before chroot:

```
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
```

But now (maybe related to efivars/efivarfs changes) this loop skips one very special sub-mountpoint - `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` and efibootmgr/grub fails.

So use this line instead:

```
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /sys/firmware/efi/efivars /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
```

Actual success story:
Debian with 4.9.0-5 (efivars) saved by Arch Linux live cd (picked just because can boot uefi out of the box) with 4.14.9-1-ARCH (efivarfs) just by bind-mounting /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Comment: `'/sys/firmware/efi': No such file or directory`

Comment: `mount --bind /sys/firmware/efi/efivars /mnt/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` before chrooting did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: after a long search this solved it for me! thank you!

Comment: needs to be the accepted answer.

Comment: On Debian this solved it! Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

You will get this error if you have booted using legacy and not the UEFI method. You need to make sure to either select the UEFI boot item in the BIOS menu, or select UEFI as the default boot method.

Comment: I found that in my boot menu, there were two entries for my USB key, and I was picking the bottom one.  The top one said UEFI: USB Key Gentoo.  That fixed it.

Comment: +1, that was the issue. On Gigabyte Aorus Master I had to press F12 and select EFI Arch to boot.

Comment: what if you need to boot legacy and only then you try to install grub efi into a second HD?

Comment: There are EFI emulators you can try.

Answer (score 8):

Running Fedora 27, I needed to mount the `efivarfs`. I did this inside the chrootfs, however this still wasn't working, as the boot entry was shown with `efibootmgr` - but after reboot it was nether booted nor was shown once back in the live OS.

What finally worked, was using grub from the live medium, drop to the shell, and enter 

`linuxefi /vmlinuz-<version> root=/dev/mapper/luks-<uuid> ro
initrdefi /initramfs-<version>.img
boot`

From the normal OS booted, I could run `grub2-install` without `chroot`, and that worked.

I am not sure whether this was just an issue with my BIOS, or there is still something more generally wrong, but this is what made `grub2-install` run without reporting any error.

`# Open encrypted root partion
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda4 a4
mount /dev/mapper/a4 /mnt
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot
mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount -t devpts pts /mnt/dev/pts/
mount -o bind /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
chroot /mnt
 # run inside the chroot:
mount /dev/sda1 /boot/efi
mount -t efivarfs efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
grub2-install`

Comment: This is the only thing that's worked for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

After some hair pulling frustration, finally found the solution to this. In my case I have a preempt-rt kernel (5.6.19-rt11 (patched)) custom compiled and installed on my EFI system.

The issue come to find out is that the preempt-rt kernels do not have efi runtime active, hence the error.

The solution is so simple:

Add `efi=runtime` to your kernel parameters in /etc/default/grub configuration.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="efi=runtime quiet"
```

Don't forget `sudo update-grub2` !

Comment: More information: https://wiki.debian.org/UEFI#Booting_from_removable_media search for "Could not read EFI vars under RT kernel"

Answer (score 1):

The error message "efi variables not supported on this system" typically occurs when the system does not support EFI (Unified Extensible Firmware Interface) variables. EFI variables are a part of the UEFI standard and are used to store various system-related information, including boot options.

This error usually means that your system's firmware is not UEFI-based, or there might be an issue with your UEFI configuration. Here's what you can do to troubleshoot and potentially resolve this issue:

1. Select UEFI boot device: Access your system's Boot menu during boot (usually by pressing F11 key) and select the UEFI boot device. (pic attached)[image: uefi boot device selected in boot menu]
2. Check UEFI Configuration: Access your system's UEFI settings during boot (usually by pressing a specific key like F2, F12, Delete, etc.) and navigate through the settings related to boot options. Make sure that your UEFI settings are configured correctly, and that the boot mode is set to UEFI if you're using a UEFI-based system.
3. Check Secure Boot: If Secure Boot is enabled in your UEFI settings, try disabling it temporarily and see if it affects the behavior of efibootmgr.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to U&L. In context of this question the OP has specifically ruled this out by disabling legacy boot and thus forcing their system to boot with UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

I was converting my BIOS/MBR system HDD to UEFI/GPT without data loss

As said, I shrunk last partition to create new **EFI System** partition with gParted and formatted it to FAT32:

```
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
1            2048        40003583   19.1 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem
2       956772352       976771071   9.5 GiB     8200  Linux swap
3        40003584       893857099   407.1 GiB   8300  Linux filesystem
4       894054400       956465151   29.8 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem
5       956465152       956772351   150.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System
```

I mounted this Partition as:

```
 sudo  mount /dev/sda5  /boot/efi
```

But after installing GRUB I also got same error

```
 sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi /dev/sda
```

I Booted with **Legacy BIOS** and of course didn't have **efivars**, makes sense...

But after i rebooted my PC to change BOOT mode to UEFI Native, I was puzzled that my PC booted normally...
like GRUB UEFI, despite error, was installed OK

I executed grub-install again and this time it went OK.

Answer (score -5):

You can't! Building and installing are two different things, the machine you build on must be uefi capable. If you want to use/install linux on uefi capable hardware gpt must already exist. You can build gpt/mbr on uefi but not both if your hardware uses old bios.

Comment: Please read the post more carefully.