# Arch install trouble

Tags: linux, arch-linux, system-installation

First time installing arch linux and I'm following this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQgyW10xD8s. When I get to 25:09, I'm told to enter this command

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --bootloader-id=grub_uefi --recheck
```

After entering this it says on my screen

```
EFI variables are not supported on this system 
EFI variables are not supported on this system 
grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: No such file or directory
```

What do I do now?

Comment: are you installing on a VM?

Comment: No I'm on a thinkpad T450s.

Comment: as far as the video link you shared. tldw. I am assuming your system supports UEFI. did you check out this solution https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91620/efi-variables-are-not-supported-on-this-system

Comment: i don't think the video you shared will cover this part because Derek Taylor is specifically creating an efi system on his vm, so it won't be relevant to him. In your actual installation, at the very start of the installation process, you need to verify that your system booted in efi mode. there are several ways of doing this, the simplest being running `ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars`, if the command doesn't throw out an error, i.e. the directory exists, you know you have booted in efi mode. They you should be able to follow along with the installation.

Comment: This looks like you have booted in legacy BIOS compatibility (CSM) mode instead of UEFI. Please double-check that and update the question accordingly.