# GRUB error after installing package

Tags: linux, arch-linux, grub

So I was following jays arch Linux installation tutorial on youtube, and after I installed the GRUB package, when I try to install GRUB, it gives me an error, here is a screenshot of that error! Thanks to whoever helps me in advance :D :)

[image: Error]

Comment: I suggest that you copy the text and paste it here, instead of a bad image of the text.

Comment: let me refer you to: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91620/efi-variables-are-not-supported-on-this-system

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem was that my PC was old and did not support efi.
I had to do it in legacy mode like this -

```bsh
pacman -S grub
grub-install /dev/sda --force
```