# I can't Install any Linux Distro on new AMD Ryzen 7 5700U Mini PC

Tags: linux, boot, uefi, bios

I'm trying to install Proxmox on a new Mini PC (GMKteck NucBox M5 **Pro** Mini PC) but keep getting the following error :

> EFI boot mode detected, mounting efivars filesystem mount:
> /sys/firmware/efi/efivars: mount(2) system call failed: Operation not
> supported.
>
> dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
>
> Installation aborted - unable to continue (type exit or CTRL-D to reboot)

I've also tried installing Ubuntu and Arch Linux and they both fail with a very similar error.

The bios/uefi (AMI) has very limited options and seems to have no option for legacy boot so it's booting in UEFI mode by default. The Pro version of this NucBox M5 is very new and I have a feeling the Bios is missing some UEFI files. Choosing 'Launch EFI Shell' from bios results in a 'Not Found' error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no "bios" (that's just an API that a computer's firmware *might* expose, and it's not like anything does the full thing anymore), what you're interacting with is already the EFI setup utility

Comment: anyways, you seem to be dropped to a rescue shell at that point; did running `dmesg` tell you anything specific about what went wrong?

Comment: Please don't [crosspost](https://superuser.com/q/1829242/332907). Ask either on Superuser or here but not both at the same time

Comment: I did a simple Google search for your model and found 2 videos on their [Guides/How-To page](https://www.gmktec.com/pages/guides-how-to-tutorial?spm=..page_2054333.footer_1.1&spm_prev=..product_b11f8b59-bb9f-45cd-ad81-85a7a7b6c002.footer_1.1) that clearly shows Ubuntu booting in UEFI mode

Comment: There's also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91620/100397

Comment: Thanks but the videos you're seeing are the standard M5 model, the M5 Pro (with 2 NVME slots) has different firmware that seems to be missing some UEFI files from what I can tell.

Comment: The other post you refer to I don't really understand, I'm not sure where I'm supposed to run those commands.

Comment: Install vmware and then install Linux (any distro) over that. Worth a try.

Comment: @mrsmith there's literally no indication for "seems to be missing some UEFI files". That's clearly not the case, your UEFI boot does boot into Linux just fine. So, what does typing `dmesg` (enter) at the point you get the message give you?